# Transfer image data to GPU via an image object?

Tags: memory, gpu, vulkan

I create an image object and bind a memory that has `VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT` tag. Then, I map the memory and copy the image data into the pointer. Finally, I unmap the memory and transfer the image to the GPU. Is that right?

What is the difference between copying CPU data to the GPU via a `VkImage` and a `VkBuffer`?

Comment: "*map memory and copy an image to it*" Copy an image via what? A Vulkan API function? Are you just copying the data on the CPU? "*Finally, unmap memory and transfer image data to GPU*" If you copied data to the memory, then it has already been "transferred". The only reason to unmap memory in Vulkan is if you're ready to delete the memory object.

Comment: I edited the question to my best understanding of the original. Please verify it still matches your original intent.

Comment: @krOoze Thank you. That's my original intent. Sorry, my English expression is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`What is the difference between copying CPU data to the GPU via a VkImage and a VkBuffer?`

If we're talking about using a staging allocation during transfer of data from CPU to GPU then basically, copying via a `VkBuffer` is the correct way to do it. Copying via `VkImage` may work in limited cases, but you'll almost certainly find yourself removing that code at a later date.

The problem with copying via a `VkImage` is that your temporary staging allocation is subject to the driver's limitations on host-visible images. You might find it works well enough for your first attempts to get something on screen, but you'll soon run into device-specific limitations that prevent `VkImage` staging buffers working for mipmaps, compressed textures, array textures or anything remotely exotic.

Basically a `VkBuffer` is the correct tool for the job of being a staging buffer for texture data. A host visible `VkImage` is not intended for staging, I believe it's largely intended to be useful for situations where you want to display a stream of images that were generated on the CPU (e.g. displaying video frames that were CPU decoded, or displaying output from a software renderer)